# My code is running smooth on VScode (mac). When on linux, I am notified of seg-faults and error messages, but I can't see what they are. What's wrong?

Tags: c, linux, macos

Our school requires that we test out our program on linux, always. Since I have a Mac I'm not able to, other than through a school server, and when I do, it notifies that I have segmentation faults and error messages, although it runs like a charm on my MacOS terminal and VScode. What's up with this? Why is it running differently on linux?

This is one of the four cases: the goal is to filter how many people fit into each of the 9 possible cases, where 9% of the input + an initial value of $200 determines which array they are placed into. (essentially, `sales[1]` is between $200 - $299, `sales[2]` between $300 - $399, etc.)

```
int salesInfo(int sales[]);

int main()
{
    int sales[9] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    salesInfo(sales);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        printf("sales[%d] = %d\n", i, sales[i]);
}

int salesInfo(int sales[])
{
    int pcent;
    int loop = 1;

    double grosales;

    while (loop == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter gross sale: ");

        scanf("%lf", &grosales);

        pcent = 200 + grosales * 0.09;

        if (pcent >= 200 && pcent <= 299)
            sales[0] += 1;
        
        else if (pcent >= 300 && pcent <= 399)
            sales[1] += 1;

        else if (pcent >= 400 && pcent <= 499)
            sales[2] += 1;

        else if (pcent >= 500 && pcent <= 599)
            sales[3] += 1;

        else if (pcent >= 600 && pcent <= 699)
            sales[4] += 1;

        else if (pcent >= 700 && pcent <= 799)
            sales[5] += 1;

        else if (pcent >= 800 && pcent <= 899)
            sales[6] += 1;

        else if (pcent >= 900 && pcent <= 999)
            sales[7] += 1;     

        else if (pcent >= 1000)
            sales[8] += 1;

        else if (grosales < 0)
            loop = 0;
    }

    return sales[9];
}
```

Comment: This is not C++. And `return sales[9];` is undefined behavior.

Comment: I changed the function to be `void` and not to return an unused value. I see no errors with Linux. A debugging `printf` statement in your function might make it easier to follow what your calculations are doing. If you are getting errors, you might post your test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes it segfault is most probably because you access `sales` out of bounds here:

```c
return sales[9];
```

You are only allowed to access `sales[0]` - `sales[8]` and when you go outside those bounds, the behavior of your program is *undefined* and it could crash or do all sorts of nasty things.

Since you are not using the return value, you could just make the function `void` and don't return anything.

---

You also double-check the ranges. If you *know* that a value is above the previous upper limit for a range, you do not need to check the lower limit for the current range:

```c
while (printf("Enter gross sale: "),
       scanf("%lf", &grosales) == 1 && grosales >= 0) // exit loop if grosales < 0
{
    pcent = 200 + grosales * 0.09;

    if (pcent >= 200 && pcent < 300)
        sales[0] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 400)
        sales[1] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 500)
        sales[2] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 600)
        sales[3] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 700)
        sales[4] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 800)
        sales[5] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 900)
        sales[6] += 1;

    else if (pcent < 1000)
        sales[7] += 1;

    else
        sales[8] += 1;
}
```

When looking at it like this, a pattern emerges. The ranges are all 100 numbers each. We could use that to calculate what index to increase. Then what's left becomes:

```c
void salesInfo(int sales[]) {
    int pcent;
    double grosales;

    while (printf("Enter gross sale: "),
           scanf("%lf", &grosales) == 1 && grosales >= 0) 
    {
        pcent = 200 + grosales * 0.09;

        if (pcent >= 1000) {  // upper limit
            ++sales[8];       // or  sales[8] += 1;
        } else {
            // calculate index for the sales slot to increase:
            int idx = (pcent - 200) / 100;
            ++sales[idx];     // or sales[idx] += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Unless you use it for something else, you could also remove the uncessary addition of 200 to `pcent`:

```c
void salesInfo(int sales[]) {
    int pcent;
    double grosales;

    while (printf("Enter gross sale: "),
           scanf("%lf", &grosales) == 1 && grosales >= 0) 
    {
        pcent = grosales * 0.09;

        if (pcent >= 800) {  // upper limit
            ++sales[8];
        } else {
            // calculate index for the sales slot to increase:
            int idx = pcent / 100;
            ++sales[idx];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- `return sales[9];` accesses the array `sales` beyond its upper boundary.  This has undefined behavior but IMHO is unlikely to produce a segmentation fault.
- you call `scanf` and `printf` without a prototype because you did not include `<stdio.h>`. This also has undefined behavior and should have been reported by the compiler if properly configured to produce useful warnings (eg: `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`).

Here is a modified version you can try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int salesInfo(int sales[]);

int main()
{
    int sales[9] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

    salesInfo(sales);

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
        printf("sales[%d] = %d\n", i, sales[i]);

    return 0;
}

void salesInfo(int sales[])
{
    for (;;) {
        double grosales;

        printf("Enter gross sale: ");
        if (scanf("%lf", &grosales) != 1 || grosales < 0)
            break;

        int pcent = grosales * 0.09;
        if (pcent < 800)
            sales[pcent / 100] += 1;
        else
            sales[8] += 1;
    }
}
```